# The two missing buffer object gl functions in Android 2.2

Tags: android, opengl-es

```
public static void glDrawElements(int mode, int count, int type, int offset)
public static void glVertexAttribPointer (int indx, int size, int type, boolean normalized, int stride, int offset)
```

Is there a way I can make these calls in Android 2.2? I don't want to start doing native code, no point at the moment as I don't need the extra speed.

Ta.
Richard E Collins. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you either need to use the NDK or 2.3 ...

Comment: Thanks, I thought that might be the case. I have added these two function calls to a small bit of NDK code and it now works on an old 2.2 device I have. Bit of a pain.